# Magento 2.0 not working properly?

Tags: magento, magento2

[image]]

I have an issue in magento 2.0. My admin page isn't working properly. The buttons like products, customers, etc. are not working. The image link is provided. They are encircled with blue colour.

Answer (score 1):

Delete magento cache and then restart server.

```
rm -rf ./var/cache
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy the static content again and see if it fixes it:

Run the following commands on the command line interface (**make sure you are in the root magento directory**)

```
rm -Rf var/*

rm -Rf pub/static/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

This will remove the old content version and recompile a new version. If the cause of your problem is a corruption / error in the static-content compliation this should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Search in `app/etc/di.xml`

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

Replace with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

After saving

- remove var/*
- remove pub/static/*
- deploy content

That's it